# Procmail: find email sent from and to the same address?

Tags: procmail

Is there a way with `procmail` (or something else?) to search for email where the `from:` and `to:` fields both contain the same address? And can it be done without needing to hardcode each and every email address in a recipe?

Basically I'm trying to find emails where the sender sends the mail to their own address then bcc's everyone else. Normally I use `notmuch` and I'm happy with that but it can't do what I'm trying to achieve here. `notmuch` can work together with `procmail` though so I was hoping someone who knows `procmail` really well could help and thus save me from needing to learn a whole new filtering system to do this one thing.

Comment: should you not search into logs rather than procmail?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, though it requires some rather obscure Procmail features, and of course, you need to understand what you are achieving.

```
:0
*   ^From:[     ]*\/[^  ].*
* $ ^To:[   ]*$\MATCH
{ ... actions ... }
```

The `\/` capture operator collects the matching string into the special variable `MATCH`. On the next line, we search for the same string in the `To:` header.  Where `$MATCH` contains the captured string, `$\MATCH` contains a regex where any regex special characters in the string have been escaped so as to match literally.  The `$` modifier is required on the recipe in order to allow interpolation of Procmail variables into the regex.

This uses the usual `[  ]*` (space or tab, zero or more) to skip over whitespace after the colon, then grabs everything starting from the first non-whitespace character.

In practice, this means that the `From:` and `To:` headers have to have identical contents.  If the sender puts in a different "real name" (which technically is just a comment), this recipe will fail to match.  For example,

```
From: Myself <me@example.net>
To: Everyone <me@example.net>
```

Here, the email terminus is identical, but the whole field is different.  If you need to cope with this scenario, maybe change the regex to match up through the first `<` before the `\/` but this will obviously depend on the precise strings you need to match; there are many possible variations.